Completeness of finite dimensional normed vector spaces without using equivalence of norms
I believe completeness of finite dimensional normed vector spaces can be proven by showing completeness of all finite dimensional vector spaces under some conveniently chosen norm and then appealing to equivalence of norms.
Is there a slick proof that avoids choosing a norm?

Here is a direct proof by induction on the dimension $n$. The case $n=0$ is trivial. We assume completeness holds for $n$-dimensional spaces, and derive it for a normed space $V$ of dimension $n+1$. Choose a decomposition $V=H\oplus\Bbb Re$ where $e$ is a nonzero vector. By induction hypothesis, $H$ is complete (for the restriction to it of the norm on $V$), hence closed in $V$. The linear functional
$$g:V\to\Bbb R,\quad x\mapsto\lambda\text{ such that }x-\lambda e\in H$$
is therefore continuous (its norm is $1/d(e,H)$).
Let now $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $V$, $\lambda_n:=g(x_n)$, and $h_n:=x_n-\lambda_ne$.
Since $g$ is continuous, $(\lambda_n)$ is Cauchy, hence so is $(h_n)$. Therefore, $\lambda_n\to\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $h_n\to h\in H$, hence $(x_n)$ converges (to $h+\lambda e$), q.e.d.
